Unwanted insertion point magnification in iOS18
I noticed the magnified insertion point in the image below after I upgraded my iPhone 13 mini to iOS 18.1.1.  It occurs if I do a long press in Reminders, Notes, Pages and perhaps others.
It presents a problem for me because I frequently reorder my lists manually with a long press but now 9 times out of 10 I get this unwanted magnification.  Is there a way to turn it off or if not, how to get it under control?


I learned elsewhere that resetting the Haptic Touch from Slow to Default would turn this feature off.

Please document your source for that info, for the benefit of others with the same question.

I learned it from another person on the Apple Community website.  I have yet to find documentation on this feature.  All I can say is that changing that setting resolved my problem.
